# What is significance of ewallet.p12.lck and cwallet.sso.lck files in oracle wallets?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I am confused regarding the significance of ewallet.p12.lck file and cwallet.sso.lck files. I assumed like any other lock files, whenever a user tries to create DB connection using wallets it creates a lck file so that no other user could use the same wallet files again. 
Is my assumption correct?
If yes, is lck file recreated every time a new connection is created using wallets?

I checked oracle wallet documentation they explaing the use of ewallet.p12 and cwallet.sso file, but do not give significance of .lck files created.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbimi/using-oracle-wallet-manager.html#GUID-D0AA8373-B0AC-4DD8-9FA9-403E345E5A71

Oracle DB version 12c

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [blog](https://anandoracledba.blogspot.com/2017/07/oracle-12cr2-how-to-setup-oracle-wallets.html), *.lck files are created while setting up the wallet files. But, these are not created when a connection is established. Also, you need to have only the ewallet.p12 and cwallet.sso for the connection to be established.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. Running JDBC drivers from 19c, our services did not start properly because the lock file could not be created. The service account does not have write access to the wallet directory, only `oracle:oracle` has.

Answer (score 0):

This is from my experience with Oracle wallet.

The lock files: `ewallet.p12.lck` and `cwallet.sso.lck` are created by Oracle UCP driver at startup after accessing the wallet files `ewallet.p12` and `cwallet.sso`, which must be located in the path pointed by `-Doracle.net.wallet_location=<path>`.

It seems they are created with `rw-------` permissions, which indicates that they are not supposed to be used by other users, but I haven't tested if that is possible.

The lock files are not recreated every time a new connection is created. They are only created at startup as a way of getting the DB connection string.

In my tests, different processes can read the same wallet files and get connections to DB, though if they start at the same time, it is likely to get a `Failed to lock - cwallet.sso.lck (Access is denied)`, which I solved duplicating the wallet files in different directory locations.